# How to correct insert this in phtml file?

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1, phtml

Help me please format this block to insert in a phtml file?

```
{{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" name="featured_list" product_count="12" template="filterproducts/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your phtml add

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock('filterproducts/latest_home_list')
                 ->setName('featured_list')
                 ->setProductCount(1)
                 ->setTemplate('filterproducts/list.phtml')
                 ->toHtml(); ?>
```